# repaint() method inside ActionListener and paintComponent method

Tags: java, paintcomponent, repaint

So i've created a Snake game but i have somekind fo a theoretical question.

Im using paintComponent to drawImage every pixel, but im also implementing ActionListener so im bound to using actionPerformed method.

my question is: why using repaint() method inside actionPerformed, what is the logic behind that?

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    checkCollusion();
    move2();
    repaint();
}
```

i tried removing repaint() method but seems like it stopped updating. myquestion is it necessary for using paintComponent again?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question.

Comment: *"myquestion is it necessary for using paintComponent again?"* - Yes

Comment: @sorifiend opps

Comment: What you should do first, is take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Swing uses a "passive" rending approach, that is, the UI isn't updated on a regular bases, instead, the RepaintManager makes decisions about what and when the UI needs to be repainted based on requests from the components. This is achieved through calling repaint.

Comment: Paint events are then dispatched to the Event Dispatching Queue, which, eventually, calls you components paintComponent method